# How to use local or instance variable in ruby code in coffeescript in haml template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, haml

I'm newer of rails and facing complex issue trying to use variable in ruby helper method in coffeescript in haml template.

Here is my code in haml

```
:coffee
  $('input#field').blur ->
    input = $('input#field').val()
    #{ ruby_method( input )}
```

ruby_helper.rb

```
def ruby_method (arg)
    if arg
        @model = Model.new(arg)
    end
end
```

This lead a error as below

> undefined local variable or method

Also tried instance variable

```
:coffee
  $('input#field').blur ->
    @input = $('input#field').val()
    #{ ruby_method( @input )}
```

This can not pass it to helper method.

How can I get javascript variable in ruby helper method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The coffeescript is running in the browser, but Ruby is on the server. If you need to communicate from your view back to your controller/model, you can submit a form and `params`will have form contents or use Ajax.  From your code, it looks like you actually want to pass `@video` from your helper method to the view.  You can refer to `@video` directly in your view (haml file) and it will render its contents as you style it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: actually I want to get @video after filled input field so passing params to controller is my desired answer. I will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Coffee Script and Rails engine Relation?**

There is no relation between rails and coffee script and nothing in rails can be accessed in coffee script.

**What can I do then ?**

Just create `def.js.erb` file in your view folder and write your javascript code. in this file you can access all instance variable in method.

**How does it calls method.js.erb ?**

use this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

this will call method.js.erb file instead of method.html.erb file.

**Hope It helps**

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't.  Ruby runs on your server, but any JavaScript (which CoffeeScript emits) you put in your template will run in the browser.

Anything you put inside a `coffee:` block *must* be valid CoffeeScript.  As others have pointed out in comments, if you want Rails to do something via JS, you need Ajax.

For example, to create a `Model` with Ajax, set up a controller with a `create` action and `post` to it in JS.

For more details, see the excellent [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) tutorial.