# Ajax in rails returns alway error callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I posted question recentry as same
[how to use local or instance variable inruby codein coffeescript in haml templ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725095/how-to-use-local-or-instance-variable-in-ruby-code-in-coffeescript-in-haml-templ)

Getting helpful comment, I'm trying to pass param to controller in ajax but it always returns error callback I can't not find the reason.

Here is my code.

**.html.haml**

```
:coffee
$('input#field').change ->
    $.ajax
        url: '/posts/gaga'
        type: "GET"
        dataType: "json"
        data: { code: $('input#field').val() }
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            alert "error"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            alert "success"
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'posts/gaga'
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def gaga
    @model = Model.new
    render nothing: true
end
```

Does anyone know what's wrong my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: Sorry actually I don't know, just get messages "error", "Object object", "Not found" by response "jqXHR", "textStatus", "errorThrown" each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your route is incorrect. It should be formatted like this at least:

`get "posts/gaga", to: "posts#gaga"`

However this might be more what you want if you already have a `resources :posts` in your routes.rb:

```
resource :posts do
  collection do
    get :gaga
  end
end
```

Because then you can avoid repeating `get "posts/..."` if you plan on adding more custom actions.