# How to pass data from controller to view with ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I posted today similar questions two times

[how-to-use-local-or-instance-variable-in-ruby-code-in-coffeescript-in-haml-templ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725095/how-to-use-local-or-instance-variable-in-ruby-code-in-coffeescript-in-haml-templ)

[ajax-in-rails-returns-alway-error-callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726121/ajax-in-rails-returns-alway-error-callback)

I'm confusing about these issues please let me ask.

I'm using ajax in haml to reload a part of page with data from controller.

Please see my code.

**.html.haml**

```
= render 'layouts/partial' #This is partial. I want to reload this part

:coffee
    $('input#field').change ->
        $.ajax
            url: '/posts/gaga'
            type: "POST"
            dataType: 'text'
            error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
                alert "error"
            success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                alert "success"
                $('div.kore').html('#{ j( render( 'layouts/partial' ) )} ');
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def gaga
    @model = Model.new("blabla")
    render :text => @model
end
```

**_partial.html.haml**

```
- if @model
    = @model.html_safe
- else
    = "No data"
```

First, I thought data can be get through @model instance variable from controller but it couldn't.

Second, I tryed to get data from ajax response data to view(_partial.html.haml) with jQuery.

Callback and response return correctly as text.

How do I pass data to view from ajax response data, or is there other ways?

Sorry for my sloppy English. I hope someone give me the clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After reread your question, I'm wondering why you want the response to be in `:text` format, I suppose json should do the job, or it isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the ajax request to `/posts/gaga.json` and in your controller's gaga method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @model }
end
```

You may want to prepare `gaga.html.haml` view file if you intend to also access `/posts/gaga` not via ajax, or just remove `format.html` if you only intend to respond in json.

---

To clarify, I see you want to reload the partial after ajax request. So rather than:

```
$('div.kore').html('#{ j( render( 'layouts/partial' ) )} ');
```

you can do something like this:

```
# inside gaga methods
format.json do
  render(json: {
    view: render_to_string(partial: 'layouts/partial', layout: false)
  })
end
```

Now inside your view:

```
= render 'layouts/partial' #This is partial. I want to reload this part

:coffee
  $('input#field').change ->
    $.ajax
      url: '/posts/gaga.json'
      type: "POST"
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        alert "error"
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        alert "success"
        $('div.kore').html(data.view)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found the solution to pass data to view but it's replacing text html with jQuery so maybe it's not correct in rails. actually I don't understand well your answer but it may be correct way rather than mine. I'll try it. Thanks!